# Lineary separate two sets

Tags: c#, c, algorithm

I have three arrays (it's written in C but that is not important, it could be any language):

```
  float x[] = {
        0.72, 0.91, 0.46, 0.03, 0.12, 0.96, 0.79, 0.46, 0.66, 0.72, 0.35, -0.16,
        -0.04, -0.11, 0.31, 0.00, -0.43, 0.57, -0.47, -0.72, -0.57, -0.25,
        0.47, -0.12, -0.58, -0.48, -0.79, -0.42, -0.76, -0.77
  };

  float y[] = {
        0.82, -0.69, 0.80, 0.93, 0.25, 0.47, -0.75, 0.98, 0.24, -0.15, 0.01,
        0.84, 0.68, 0.10, -0.96, -0.26, -0.65, -0.97, -0.03, -0.64, 0.15, -0.43,
        -0.88, -0.90, 0.62, 0.05, -0.92, -0.09, 0.65, -0.76      
  };

  int outputs[] = {
      -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
  };
```

First two arrays are X and Y coordinates of a points on two dimensional plane.

Third array decides if the point is from set 1 or set -1.

I need an algorithm that will linearry separate these two sets of points. I.e. it should return a and b coeficients from this equation:

```
y = a*x + b
```

Which is a general line equation.

Look at the first image here:

http://dynamicnotions.blogspot.com/2008/09/single-layer-perceptron.html

To better understanbd what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Support Vector Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) will do what you want (albeit somewhat difficult to implement)

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at your graphs on the first page, but I am still not clear what you actually want as a result. My guess is you want the best co-efficients for an approximation of a linear line which "best fits" the two groups of points ? It appears your "neural net" for the Perceptron does exactly that, already. Might help to clarify ?

Comment: Yes, the Perceptron works and after the learning algorithm it can say if a point is from set 1 or -1. But I don't know how to get the actual line that separates the two sets from the Perceptron output. I know it has something to do with its weights.

Comment: if you trained a perceptron to do this, you could recover the slope and intercept. the slope would be the coefficient on the x input over the coefficient on the y input. the intercept would be the constant you used for your bias times the weight on the bias. simple?

Comment: Which coeficient on the x input? There are more x inputs and y inputs.

Comment: You have one input for x, one for y, and one for bias. Optimize over all data points.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now, I have used GD to draw a nice graph and the line I computed separates the two sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back from the perceptron solution, just put in "zero" as the target and solve for what inputs give a zero in the perceptron formula, that's an answer.

More generally you probably want this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis

Answer (score 0):

If you try all linear edges (extrapolated to infinity) of the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of one of the sets, then that should give you a line that separates the two sets, otherwise it's not possible to linearly separate them.